# Can I change Wikipedia lookup language on a Kindle Fire?

Tags: kindle-fire

When I select the Wikipedia lookup on my Kindle Fire (5th generation), the text displayd in the box is always in English and it redirects to English articles. Is it possible to set up the language to Portughese?